# Hyper tuning reduce the accuracy score, why?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter, gridsearchcv

I have performed hyper tuning grid CV search on KNN model. The actual accuracy score for my KNN was accuracy of 42.31 % without performing hyper tuning. However, after performing hyper tuning, the accuracy score has gone down to 27.97 %?
I would like to know why this happened? I performed Near Miss (under sampling) to balance my dataset.

Comment: So you had an initial $K$ with accuracy of $42.31\%$ accuracy and have evaluated different $K$, where the best $K^{*}$ resulted in $27.97\%$ accuracy ?

Comment: We need more details. What set are these scores reported for? What's the hyperparameter grid, the default hyperparameters, the selected hyperparameters? When in your pipeline do you undersample?

Comment: Try to make sure that the default values of parms are part of your parm-values dict if that parm is in the dict. *e.g. n_neighbors=5, *, weights='uniform', algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, p=2, metric='minkowski', metric_params=None*